# Constant-time code

Tags: c++

I have two pieces of code snips, which should be investigated on fulfilling the constant-time requirement. If it is not fulfilled, the code should be revised.

First:

```
unit8_t a[128]
unit8_t data[128]
if(k)  //k is a secret variable
  memcpy(data,a,128);
```

This snip of code does not fulfil the constant-time requirement because if k is false, no copy instruction will be done, and the execution time will be much faster than by doing memcpy. But I don't really know, how to change to fulfil the requirement.

Second:

```
uint8_t a[128], b[128];
uint8_t data[128];
memcpy(data, k ? a : b, 128);
```

I guess it also not fulfils the constant-time requirement because of the ternary operator which makes a branch. But here I am not sure and I also don't know how to rewrite the code.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think your question is more for a programing forum than a security one, from my point of view or course.

Comment: what is this code supposed to do? Because if the only requirement is constant time, then I can replace the whole code with a nop `;` and that would execute in a constant-time

Comment: This seems like a question about hardening code from time-analysis-based attacks for security purposes, especially considering the migration.

Comment: If you consider a conditional branch to not have constant time, then I don't think it's possible to write code that does anything very useful in constant time. Almost all useful code contains some conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

First example:

```
unit8_t a[128]
unit8_t data[128]
if(k)  //k is a secret variable
  memcpy(data,a,128);
```

lets branch it:

branch A for k == true:

```
 unit8_t a[128];
 unit8_t data[128];
 memcpy(data,a,128);
```

branch B for k == false:

```
 unit8_t a[128];
 unit8_t data[128];
 //no memcpy
```

Second example:

```
uint8_t a[128], b[128];
uint8_t data[128];
memcpy(data, k ? a : b, 128);
```

branch A for k == true:

```
uint8_t a[128], b[128];
uint8_t data[128];
memcpy(data, a, 128); //from a to data
```

branch B for k == false:

```
uint8_t a[128], b[128];
uint8_t data[128];
memcpy(data, b, 128); //from b to data
```

Clearly both examples performs different tasks but second one may be execute in same steps for both branches. But there is a big "but" in there as compiler may optimize this to code that is not identical for both branches and will not provide constant time execution for this task.

Answer (score 0):

With no other details, we cannot assume the optimizer is 'smart' here.
In the first case, you can add

```
else
memcpy(a, data, 128);
```

and in the second case, there is nothing to add.

Let me add some considerations that could affect the timing

1. A good optimizer will detect how a, b or data are being used. It therefore may decide that some of the calls to memcpy are redundant and will skip those. (or branch before the function returns).
2. Caching - if a, b or data are already cached, the access may be faster. This way copying a to data or data to a may be performed in different timing
3. Branch prediction - even with an 'even' if/else statement, the compiler can generate an asymmetric code, due to prediction. Multiple re-runs can detect the anomalies.

However, due to the simplicity of the examples, it looks like a first exercise in timing attacks. I wouldn't worry about all these things now.